# Explain this C code snippet — what will happen with printf() function arguments?

Tags: c, string, function, escaping, printf

Can anyone please explain what will be the output and how? I am unable to understand the `printf()` function arguments. I want to know the difference between 
**1 and 2**, and **3 and 4** `printf()` statements. Normally in `printf()`, we should give control string as first argument. But even though interchanging arguments, will I get the same output?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str;
    str = "%s";
    printf("%s\n", str);  //.....1
    printf(str, "%s\n");  //.......2
    printf(str, "K\n");   //.......3
    printf("K\n", str);   //........4
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first argument to `printf()` is a string — it may be (and very often is) a string literal, but it does not have to be.  The first argument controls the output from `printf()`; the others may alter the output. The first two output `%s` and a newline; the third and fourth both output `K` and a newline.  Note that the fourth doesn't need the `str` argument.  You should be able to see that by running the code, and by thinking carefully about what the `printf()` function sees.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to put the code into a compiler and look at the output. It will probably give better insight of things than asking in Stack Overflow.

The expected output is:

1. [%s\n] because str contains %s and it will be printed as is.
2. [%s\n] because str contains the format and the second argument will be printed. This form is very dangerous if str comes from the user.
3. [K\n] same as 2.
4. [K\n] str is ignored. gcc will warn you if configured correctly through command-line arguments.

Conclusion — always use #1.

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` function arguments are comprised of

> (1) an initial `shift state`
>   (2) `format string`
>   (3) `list of arguments`

In your case you have:

```
printf("%s\n",str);  //.....1
```

No shift, a format string that takes the sting `str` = `%s` and prints it literally.

```
printf(str, "%s\n");//.......2
```

The values of `str` has no numeric shift (again `0`) and a literal `%s` which is printed.

```
printf(str, "K\n"); //.......3
```

Here again you have a value of `str` and initial shift `0`, but include a literal format string `K` which is printed.

```
printf("K\n",str);   //........4
```

Finally, you have a format string with an insufficient number of conversion specifiers which generates the warning:

```
foo.c:11:1: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
 printf("K\n",str);   //........4
```

but which contains the literal format string `K` which again is printed. In sum the output of the code being:

```
%s
%s
K
K
```